# Use of "that are the element of secondary flows"

Tags: sentence-construction

Is use of "that are the element of secondary flows" in the following sentences correct grammatically and conceptually? If it is not , kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> Fig. 13 presents 3 dimensional stream lines around the blades....
>
> This figure also shows horse-shoe vortices **that are the element of
>   secondary flows**.

Comment: This is a rather technical excerpt, and not everyday language. Therefore, this seems like a proofreading request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sentence

> This figure also shows horse-shoe vortices **that are the element of secondary flows**.

using the definite article "the" would be understood to mean that there is only a single type of secondary flow, however there is more than one type of secondary flow as shown here

[image]
<sub>(source: [cfms.org.uk](http://qnet-ercoftac.cfms.org.uk/w/images/thumb/8/8b/UFR2-10_figure_1.png/600px-UFR2-10_figure_1.png))</sub>


So, it might be more appropriate to use

> This figure also shows horse-shoe vortices that are **an** element of secondary flows.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me reference of your answer? I think that this reference is good for studying.

Comment: Image reference [here](http://qnet-ercoftac.cfms.org.uk/w/images/thumb/8/8b/UFR2-10_figure_1.png/600px-UFR2-10_figure_1.png)